# Join data on 2 columns in the same query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to join string data using `FOR XML` technique. In the result I would like to get 2 different columns with joined data. I can do 2 sub-selects to achieve that, but the problem is that the table I'll use in real will be just huge and scanning it 2 times will add a lot of overhead. Is it possible to join this data in a single run?

```
DROP TABLE #test;
GO

CREATE TABLE #test
(
    col1 VARCHAR(MAX)
  , col2 VARCHAR(MAX)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('1value', '2value'), ('11value', '22value');

SELECT SUBSTRING((   SELECT t.col1 + ';' AS [text()]
                       FROM #test AS t
                     FOR XML PATH(''))
               , 1
               , 20000) AS Note
```

Expected result:

```
| col1          | col2          |
|1value;11value | 2value;22value|
```

Comment: have you tried `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I would try and stay away from `FOR XML` as it is quite old and very rarely used in my experience. Judging by your expected output though, you want to concatenate strings from two different rows, not columns. This requires two distinct data sets, and thus two table scans. You can at least make it look nice with a CTE though?

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT
    rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columns_to_order_by),
    col1, col2
  FROM #test
)
SELECT
  cur.col1 + prev.col1, cur.col2 + prev.col2, 
FROM CTE cur
INNER JOIN CTE prev on prev.rownum = cur.rownum - 1
```

Comment: This query will return 2 rows if you add one more record. So, basically it just adds 2 levels

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE #test;
GO

CREATE TABLE #test
(
    col1 VARCHAR(MAX)
  , col2 VARCHAR(MAX)
);
GO

INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('1value', '2value'), ('11value', '22value');

SELECT STUFF((   SELECT ';' + t.col1  AS [text()]
                       FROM #test AS t
                     FOR XML PATH(''))
               , 1
               ,1
               , '') AS Note,
STUFF((   SELECT ';' + t.col2  AS [text()]
                       FROM #test AS t
                     FOR XML PATH(''))
               , 1
               ,1
               , '') AS Note2
```

-- Second Way

DECLARE @Col1 VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @Col2 VARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @Col1=COALESCE(@Col1+';', '')+t.col1
      ,@Col2=COALESCE(@Col2+';', '')+t.col2
FROM #test AS t

SELECT @Col1,@Col2

Comment: in your example there are 2 calls to the table. I can do the same by just repeating substring clause. My question was if it is possible to do that with the single table scan...